# JQuery Click/Load when mysql is run it displays the previous page before it loads the active page

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a main page called dashboard.php
When a user clicks a link it grabs a newpage from the href and loads it into the dashboard.php div called main interface. In the newpage that is loaded shows the whole version of dashboard.php in it and then loads my new page in the div underneath it.

My code for the Jquery is as follows:

```
// Navigation Link Redirect
        $('.NavChange').click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             $(".main-interface").load($(this).attr('href'));
          });
```

This is an example of the link i use as well:

```
<a href='settings/viewuser.php' class="NavChange">View Profile</a>
```

This is a picture of it loading twice when I click the link view profile

[image: This is the picture of it loading the dashboard page twice when I click view profile.]

I know its because for some reason the jquery doesn't know to load dashboard with a diffrent .main-interface div that has the page loaded when it runs the jquery but for the life of me can't seem to figure out how to correct it.

Edit: Progress #1 - I found out that I was inadvertantly including the dashboard.php page into the newpage.php because i wanted to pass a variable to run a mysql query in the php. Now i need to figure out how to pass a variable without including the dashboard.php in the click event.

Comment: its not loading twice, the new page also has the header and jquery is inserting the entire new page in your old page. Hence the effect.

Comment: Any idea for jquery to remember that i want to load the new page instead of the original stuff in main-interface?

Comment: Also the new page only has a div that is Jquery ui widget as a container with a call to some php to output a table in that container. I have no headers or anything from dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

OKay. jQUery is doing what you are asking it to do. You are doing,

`$(".main-interface").load($(this).attr('href'));`.

So it loads the new page (which contains the whole page including header part) into `.main-interface`.

You need to select only the body part and insert into `.main-interface`.

I am assuming that this body part is enclosed withing `.main-interface` in the other page as well.

So you could select that part in the load statement like this:

`$(".main-interface").load($(this).attr('href') + " .main-interface");`.

for more info http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: the newpage.php (well call it that for this example) has none of the original dashboard.php in it. newpage.php just has a jquery widget container with some sql to output a table with information in it. but for some reason i guess it refreshes when the jquery loads so it brings the original main-interface content and then outputs the newpage.php underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: What I did was sent a variable within the href link and stored it in newpage.php as a variable for mysql query and got rid of my dashboard.php include statement that was replicating it twice.

Works like a charm!

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, new page did have the dashboard because of that include statement. Instead of doing all this you could have just selected the part without the dashboard using the query selector provided in my answer.